# How to set checkbox state in a table cell based on another cell's value in Django templates using jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, html-table

I am trying to set a checkbox inside a cell in each row of a table depending on another cell's value **in the row**. I am accessing the cell with the value, comparing with a pre-determined value (say "L") and if found, marking the checkbox `true`. So far I have tried the following:

**HTML**

```
<table id="listTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Doc Num</th>
            <th>Short Text</th>
            <th>Locked</th> 
            <th>Lock Type</th> 
            <th>Frequency</a></th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="filterTableBody">
        {% for data in prod_sch %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{% url 'prod_schdle' data.pk %}">{{ data.doc_num }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ data.desc }}</td>
                <td><input type='checkbox' class='chk_locked' id='id_chkbox_locked' disabled='true'></td> 
                <td>{{ data.lock_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.freq }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#listTable tr').each(function() {
        var val_status_lock = $(this).find('td').eq(3).html();
        if ( val_status_lock === 'L' ) {
            $('.chk_locked').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Currently, checkboxes of all the rows are getting checked **true**, even for the rows with a different cell value.

How to mark checkboxes of only those rows where the cell value is **L**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same `find()` approach as for the `td` so you isolate the checkbox within that row

```
if ( val_status_lock === 'L' ) {
   $(this).find('.chk_locked').prop('checked', true);
}
```